# React JS and css pseudo element ::after ::before

Tags: reactjs, sass, pseudo-element

As a React beginner I'm currently struggling with it for rendering styled components with the use of pseudo elements ::after and ::before.

Here is the sass style for a button: https://jsfiddle.net/r8qwhfvx/
It is what I try to achieve in React: changing the style of my button on hover using pseudo elements.

But how to use ::after / ::before in the className of button components for instance? JSX syntax unable the use of ::after / ::before in the components className.

I'm just able to write this:

```
return(
    <button className='infoBtn'></button>
);
```

Please check jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**className** JSX attribute is a string variable, which will be set as the **class** attribute value on the HTML element when it will be rendered by React. CSS pseudo elements can appear in CSS code, not as a class name for a HTML element.

So you need to give a class name to your button using className JSX attribute, then define CSS rules for this class. To do so you need to choose a strategy to setup CSS in your React app. There is multiple solutions :

- use a plain old CSS file imported in your index.js or index.html
- use a plain old style element in your index.html (these 2 options are global, like in plain old 90's web development)
- use JSX "style" attribute : `<Component style={{here put CSS object}} />` : https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/
- use [CSS modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) (if you are using [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)) : https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/
- use [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) or any other [CSS-in-JS](https://speakerdeck.com/vjeux/react-css-in-js) option, there is [a lot of solutions](https://github.com/MicheleBertoli/css-in-js), I mention styled-components since it is one of the most popular

With all of these options you will be able to use CSS pseudo-element. For SASS you may have to setup a CSS preprocessor. If you are using create-react-app (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/) or styled-components (https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#can-i-nest-rules) you're good to go, it's build in. Well for styled-components I'm not sure if it is a true full SASS support though.

Good luck with that !

Comment: Thank you for your answer and all the documentation.

Comment: Happy to help ! Don't hesitate to accept my answer if it was useful.